# Wildcards in exclude-filelist for duplicity

Tags: backup, rsync, duplicity, rdiff-backup, wildcards

I am trying to exclude a "bulk" folder in each home directory from the backup. For this purpose, I have a line

```
- /data/home/*/bulk
```

in my exclude-filelist file.

However, this doesn't seem to be recognised:

```
Warning: file specification '/data/home/*/bulk' in filelist exclude-list-test.txt
doesn't start with correct prefix /data/home/kay/bulk.  Ignoring.
```

Is there a way?

BTW: is the format in general compatible with rsync's exclude-from? I have a working exclude list for that, where this wildcard expression works.

Answer (score 1):

The two formats are not compatible, so you have to do some changes to the list to get it to work. If you want to re-use your exclude list from rsync you have to:

- use `--exclude-globbing-filelist` on duplicity
- prefix each line of your rsync's exclude list file with `**`.

You can achieve the latter with sed:

```
sed -e 's/^/**\//' rsync_backup_exclude_file >> duplicity_backup_exclude_file
```